# What is the name of the brace?

Tags: wood

I have a chair that broke and I need to buy two of these to replace them. I took the chair to a wood repair place or furniture repair place and he told me he would charge me more than the whole set is worth just to repair it. I know I can do it myself if I have the wood parts. Are these available or do I have to have them made?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: In terms of what these might be called, I think both *corner brackets* and *diagonal braces* might both be terms used to describe them. It's quite likely other terms exist too, even for something as simple as this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know these are not available to buy as parts, except perhaps for 90° corners such as would be found on tables. Normally they'd simply be made in the factory or workshop that produces the chairs as part of the making process.

The existing diagonal braces are possibly repairable, and the repaired parts could be as good as new (potentially actually *slightly* stronger in fact). If you use PVA-type glues — white or yellow "wood glue" — you'll need the glue and one or more strong clamps.

---

As you already know, there's more going on here than just the split corner brace, as the broken dowel visible in the photo shows. A full repair to a chair with one or more breaks like this is not especially complicated or difficult, but requires:

- replacement dowels;
- a drill and bits (the largest being the right size to create matching holes for the new dowels);
- adhesive (PVA or slow-setting epoxy recommended);
- a selection of suitable clamps.

Comment: as far as the matching holes, I've found that with small drill bits you can drill a lot of hole in the old dowel and use an awl or small chisel to clean out the original holes, (and that way you know they will line up)

Comment: The difficulty here is that the other corners are probably still attached, which makes getting at the old dowels awkward. Since it’s paint grade, I’d be tempted to drill through everything from the outside and push in long dowels.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate it. I'll try to find someone who can make me two pieces or I'll try to do it myself. I already rigged the other side using a handful of L brackets but without this side to support it, I need wood again.